# reset a recurring multiindex in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a pandas data frame in python coming from a pd.concat with a recurring multiindex:

```
        customer_id
0   0   46841769
    1   4683936
1   0   8880872
    1   8880812
0   0   8880873
    1   1000521
1   0   1135488
    1   5388773
```

No, I will reset only the first index of the multiIndex, so that I get a recurring number on the index. Something like this:

```
        customer_id
0   0   46841769
    1   4683936
1   0   8880872
    1   8880812
2   0   8880873
    1   1000521
3   0   1135488
    1   5388773
```

In general, I have around 5 Mio records and not the biggest machine. So I'm looking for a memory efficient solution for that.

ignore_index=True in pd.concat do not works, because then I lose the Multiindex.

Many thanks

Comment: What is your `concat` code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert first level by [`get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html) [`to_series`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.to_series.html), then compare it with [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html)ed values and add [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) for count and last use [`MultiIndex.from_arrays`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_arrays.html):

```
a = df.index.get_level_values(0).to_series()
a = a.ne(a.shift()).cumsum() - 1

mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([a, df.index.get_level_values(1)], names=df.index.names)

df.index = mux
```

Or:

```
df = df.set_index(mux)
```

---

```
print (df)
     customer_id
0 0     46841769
  1      4683936
1 0      8880872
  1      8880812
2 0      8880873
  1      1000521
3 0      1135488
  1      5388773
```

Comment: Thanks for answer.
If I do that, then I will lose my multiindex and get only a single index for the data. However I need this 0,1 construct.

Comment: Cool, thanks works. Many thanks for the fast answer. Made my day.